# ValueError: "input_length" is 47, but received input has shape (None, 47, 18704)

Tags: machine-learning, keras-layer, embedding

```
input = Input(shape=(47,vocab_length))

print(input.shape)

X = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_length,output_dim = embedding_size,input_length=47)(input)

print(X.shape)

X = Reshape([47,embedding_size,1])(X)
```

Above given is the part of my code, here I am getting an error in Embedding layer, as shown-

```
ValueError: "input_length" is 47, but received input has shape (None, 47, 18704)
```

Note here that `vocab_length` and `embedding_size` are integers.

Please help me out!

Thanks

Comment: `X = Reshape([47, 1, embedding_size])(X)`, Keras timeseries dimension is the second one not the last one.

Comment: The problem is in the Embedding command I don't get how changing the arguments in the Reshape()(X) layer which is after the Embedding layer will makeit run. And I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: Also, write more info regarding why `Reshape()` is needed etc.

Comment: Here Reshape is required for the next Conv2D() layer where the rank of the array should be 4 thus I am adding one more channel to it keeping the whole length same.

Answer (score 0):

So, further I tried making my own customed layer similar to the Embedding layer. But in it I am getting some error as described below.
'''

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,shape_0=1,shape_1=1):
      super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
      self.w = self.add_weight(
          shape=(shape_0,shape_1), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
      )
    

    def call(self, inputs):
      return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w)
embedding_size = 300
vocab_length = 18704
input = Input(shape=(47,vocab_length))



X = MyLayer(vocab_length,embedding_size)(input)
X = Reshape([47,embedding_size,1])(X)
```

'''
Here it gives error in Reshape layer saying the target length should be same as the original length of the input. But it is same i.e. input shape = [47,embedding_size] and target size = [47,embedding_size,1]
'''

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

'''

Comment: Here I checked the shape of X after the Embedding layer using print(X.shape) it showed (None,47,300) which is what it has to be. I am not able to figure out why is it giving size error in Reshape layer.

Comment: You should post this as an Update to your question and not as an answer, also post what is your data type, shape and its example.

Comment: Sorry for that....  input variable is a tensor. and shape is already mentioned above. I guess there is some problem in MyLayer() class, can you just check this.

Comment: I think instead of `Reshape()` look into `tf.expand_dims` as it is actually made for doing this stuff. Actually, if `47` is the number of examples then replacing `47` by `None` would make the original code work.

Comment: Ok so I put this expand layer statement in the MyLayer class itself before returning in the call def in the class, as follows- '''k = tf.matmul(inputs, self.w)
        return tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(k) ''' further I am using the output of the MyLayer in Conv2D layer it gives me following error.

Comment: ValueError: Depth of input (1) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (18704) for '{{node conv2d_150/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](my_layer_24/ExpandDims, conv2d_150/convolution/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,47,300,1], [2,300,18704,1].

Comment: I am sure that there is some error in the class itself. As when I give some other input to the conv layer it gives correct output.